# Why doesn't Angular let user define @Output events starting with 'on'?

Tags: javascript, angular, security, events

I was writing a component, with an output EventEmitter called onUploaded, but angular gave me an error telling me to use (uploaded) instead, as it is not allowed to have bindings starting with 'ono' for security issues. it made me wonder why is that exactly? what are the security issues?

Comment: it looks like you used brackets `[onUploaded]` instead of paranthesis `(onUploaded)` to bind to outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can read on [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#dont-prefix-output-properties)

**Don't prefix output properties Style 05-16**

> Why? This is consistent with built-in events such as button clicks.
>
> Why? Angular allows for an alternative syntax on-*. If the event
>   itself was prefixed with on this would result in an on-onEvent binding
>   expression.

You can also read [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13997)
This is to avoid unpredictable behavior in your application.
Hope that's clear.